# Logrotate doesn't work automatically (using size limit)

Tags: logrotate

It seems that my rotation is not working. If I execute the logrotate manually it's working like it should. The logrotate is ran because I can see it in the logs. Here's what I have:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

/home/www/logs/access_log {
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    size 2G
    compress
    dateext
    maxage 30
    postrotate
    /usr/local/bin/apachectl -k graceful
    endscript
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have a `cron` job (or some other scheduler) that periodically runs `logrotate`? It's not going to just magically run on its own...

Comment: Yes... It writes a log every time it ran.

Comment: It is also running other rotations in that same file so don't worry it is not running by magic.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but someone might find this helpful.

The default rotation settings indicate weekly rotation, but your configuration for access log below specifies rotation by size.

These settings will not work at the same time. It's either time or size.
For access logs, I would advise daily rotation.

If your logs grow over 2GB during the day, then you will need to run logrotate hourly. This ensures that logrotate will check the size of your log and rotate accordingly.

This however, implies that you have to add time stamp to your logs, because you would want to have multiple logs for the same day, right?

There is also maxsize parameter for logrotate, and it's supposed to work together with time based rotation (daily, weekly etc) but I'm not sure if it works. You will need to experiment.